# Analyzing memory leak

Tags: c++, macos, memory-leaks, gdb, instruments

Sorry for the generic title but I didn't know how to better clarify.

I'm writing a C++ program on MacOS 10.8.3. I tried to analyze if for memory leaks using Apple's Instruments and here's the results

[image]

Unfortunately (don't know why actually) the Call Tree shows no entries, so I wasn't able to understand which call is responsible for the leak.

However, Instruments shows the address of the leaked memory so I opened gdb and attached it to the running process, in order to analyze the content of the memory and have some hints about the error. Here's what gdb returned

```
(gdb) x/s 0x7fa0f3400720
0x7fa0f3400720:  "OS_dispatch_queue_specific_queue"
(gdb) x/s 0x7fa0f34005d0
0x7fa0f34005d0:  "OS_xpc_connection"
(gdb) x/s 0x7fa0f3400640
0x7fa0f3400640:  "OS_dispatch_object"
(gdb) x/s 0x7fa0f3400660
0x7fa0f3400660:  "OS_dispatch_queue"
(gdb) x/s 0x7fa0f3400680
0x7fa0f3400680:  "OS_dispatch_source"
(gdb) x/s 0x7fa0f34006a0
0x7fa0f34006a0:  "OS_dispatch_semaphore"
(gdb) x/s 0x7fa0f34006c0
0x7fa0f34006c0:  "OS_dispatch_group"
```

and so on. Obviously I don't have any of this strings in my code.

I'm making massive use of pthreads to speed up the computation. May these leaks be caused by some mistakes in my use of pthreads or the cause is something else? Actually what surprise me is that the leaks are (relatively) small, while, if there was a design error in my code, I would expect much bigger leaks (the code runs for a while and I'm creating and destroying hundreds - if not thousands - of threads).

If necessary, I can show parts of my code (although the project is not very big, it's surely too large to post it here).

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Is there some reason that you're not linking with Core Foundation?

Comment: Not really, I simply don't need it so there was no reason to link it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Instruments. You can try **[valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)**, it is very useful to detect memory leak.

Comment: valgrind actually has two relevant tools for the problem: --memcheck will check for memory leaks, and --helgrind will check for race conditions. Unfortunately, I believe --helgrind is not available on Mac OS X.